# PHP integer rounding problems

Tags: php, floating-point, integer

`echo (int) ( (0.1+0.7) * 10 );`

Why does the above output 7?  I understand how PHP rounds towards 0, but isn't `(0.1+0.7) * 10` evaluated as a float and then casted as an integer?

Thanks!

Comment: i think this happens in any language, and its because the way floating point numbers are handled internally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a loss in precision when decimals are converted internally to their binary equivalent. The computed value will be something like 7.9+ instead of the expected 8.

If you need a high degree of accuracy, use the [GMP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.gmp.php) family of functions or the [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) library.

Answer (score 2):

See the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> It is typical that simple decimal
>   fractions like 0.1 or 0.7 cannot be
>   converted into their internal binary
>   counterparts without a small loss of
>   precision. This can lead to confusing
>   results: for example,
>   floor((0.1+0.7)*10) will usually
>   return 7 instead of the expected 8,
>   since the internal representation will
>   be something like 7.9.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explained WHY this happens.  This should get you what you want:

```
echo (int) round( (0.1+0.7) * 10 );
```

Just *round* the float before casting it to an int.

Comment: also, its recommented you dont actually use floats for currency calculations, because of this loss of precision

Answer (score 0):

I don't have php installed, but in python:

```
$ python
>>> 0.1+0.7
0.79999999999999993
>>>
```

Not all numbers in base 10 can be represented precisely in base 2 system. Check Wikipedia article:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_numeral_system

section Fractions in Binary. In particular, this line:

```
Fraction    Decimal     Binary  Fractional Approx.
1/10    0.1     0.000110011...  1/16+1/32+1/256...
```

1/10 cannot be represented in a finite way in base 2. Thus, 0.1 + 0.7 cannot be precisely calculated in base 2.

**Never** assume floating-point calculations are precise, it will bite you sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

1/10 cannot be represented in a finite number of binary digits, just like 1/3 cannot be represented as a finite number of base-10 digits.  Therefore you are actually adding together 0.09999999999999... and 0.69999999999999... -- the sum is *almost* 8, but not quite.